# HDFS - HBase replication not working

Tags: apache, hbase, hdfs, predictionio

I'm using Prediction-IO for a POC.

**Issue** : I have set HDFS replication factor as 1.
If I create any sample file on HDFS , then replication factor is 1.

But whenever I try to load data using Prediction-IO( which uses HBase) then all files created have replication factor of 3.

[image: Sample File]

[image: Prediction-IO , HBase file]
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default HBase will pick replication factor as 3.
To specify replication factor add following property in **hbase-site.xml**

```
<property>
   <name>dfs.replication</name>
   <value>1</value>
</property>
```

I had to update **hbase-site.xml** on all region servers.